# docker-compose wordpress:latest different default port

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a dockerised site. It will be a node powered app as the front-end and will use wordpress as a headless cms. I've created a docker-compose.yml file that looks like this:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:80"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

the problem is that wordpress is using port 80. I want to expose the node app on port 80 and have wordpress only accessible on some other port number. I've played around with the wordpress `ports` mapping but it always seems to sit on port 80:

e.g.

[image: port 80 usage]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose node app on port 80 then portyouwanttoexpose:nodecurrentusingport. 
Here on your command you have done is exposing port 80 to 3000 exactly opposite. 
I think first use correct ports for node and then try other ports for exposing your wordpress cms